# Bigquery to find max losing streak for each perso

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Assume I have a database like this. The original database has millions of data for ~1000 unique names.

What I am after is to find the maximum losing streak for each person when sorted by date.

What I am looking for is a query that have all unique names in 1 column and the maximum losing streak they had in the next one.

[image: Sample Database]

Comment: How to treat `SKIP`? does it breaks sequence or just should be ignored?

Comment: SKIP to be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option to consider

```
select distinct name, count(*) streak from (
  select name, 
    count(*) over win - countif(win_loss = 'LOSS') over win as grp
  from your_table
  window win as (partition by name order by date)
)
where win_loss = 'LOSS'
group by name, grp
qualify 1 = rank() over(partition by name order by count(*) desc)
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Your solution worked but not quite there. In the example above, ABC has 3 losing streak before first win and then 4 losing streak before next (ignoring  SKIP). So the answer has to be 4 not 3.

Comment: obviously because of 'SKIP' was not ignored as it was not clear how to treat it :o)

Comment: Yeah. Sorry that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

(Updated - ***SKIP to be ignored***)

You might consider below trick.

1. Firstly, generate sequences of loss(**1**) and others(**0**) over time per user.

> ABC - **111011110**
>
> XYZ - **1111111011**

2. If the sequence is split with delimiter **0**, you will get multiple losing-streaks.

   [image]
3. Find a sequence with max length from **losing-streaks** array.

```sql
SELECT Name,
       (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(r)) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(results, '0')) r) AS losing_streaks
  FROM (
    SELECT Name, 
           STRING_AGG(
             CASE WinLoss 
               WHEN 'LOSS' THEN '1'
               WHEN 'SKIP' THEN NULL 
               ELSE '0'
             END, '' ORDER BY Date
           ) AS results
      FROM sample_table
     GROUP BY 1
  );

+------+----------------+
| Name | losing_streaks |
+------+----------------+
| ABC  |              4 |
| XYZ  |              7 |
+------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

> SKIP to be ignored

> ABC has 3 losing streak before first win and then 4 losing streak before next (ignoring SKIP). So the answer has to be 4 not 3

to address above you can use below version

```
select distinct name, count(*) streak from (
  select name, win_loss, 
    countif(win_loss != 'SKIP') over win - countif(win_loss = 'LOSS') over win as grp
  from your_table
  window win as (partition by name order by date)
)
where win_loss = 'LOSS'
group by name, grp
qualify 1 = rank() over(partition by name order by count(*) desc)
```

with output

[image]